# Is there a difference between verbs 'bereisen' & 'reisen'

Tags: word-choice

Recently I heard the verb **bereisen** which means to tour, travel. I have been using **reisen** to mean the same.

> Do these two verbs have the exact same meaning? Is there a context in which one verb fits better than the other? What specific meaning is added by the prefix 'be' here?

Please give some examples if they are used in specific context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Bereisen** can only be applied to an area/country. It means that you travelled around in an area for a while.

You could say

> In seiner Jugend bereiste er zahlreiche Länder Afrikas.

or

> Sie bereiste Kanada und die USA.

or even

> Als Journalist hatte er die Gelegenheit, beinahe die ganze Welt zu bereisen.

But you would not use bereisen for a single trip to one city.

**Reisen** is a lot more general and does not say anything about the duration of your visit to the destination.

Answer (score 6):

Above all, "bereisen" needs an accusative object, i.e. a country or region that you are travelling *to*.

Bereisen describes a much more leisurely way of travelling, where the route becomes the destination. It also has an old-fashioned ring to it. You'll use *reisen* in most circumstances these days.

> Von 1853 bis 1856 bereiste Dr. Livingstone ganz Südafrika.
>
> Wir wollen nächstes Jahr im Februar Laos und Kambodscha auf eigene Faust bereisen.

Answer (score 3):

"Bereisen" can only be used if your travel tour covers different parts of the country/area you are visiting, whereas "reisen" could also describe a one-stop trip.

It implies that a certain degree of immersion into the travel destination took place. About a person who traveled a lot in his life you can say: "Er ist bereist".

Comment: I'd probably say "weitgereist". "Bereist" as an adjective sounds strange to me.

Answer (score 1):

Der Unterschied liegt in"ich bereise ein Land" und " ich reise in ein Land"

Comment: You do not need to open an account but if you register this will give you the advantage to collect reputation points and gain privileges such as voting and commmenting. It is entirely free (and a lot of fun, really). If you decide to stay unregistered for a while then please try to not create a new unregistered account everytime you come here. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/reisen), there are three different meanings to 'reisen'.

'bereisen' can be swapped with 'reisen', but 'reisen' does not always have the same meaning, so you can't always exchange 'reisen' with 'bereisen'. To address your question: They can have the same meaning, but you have to decide based on given context. Edit: If you want to exchange 'bereisen' with 'reisen' you will need to add for example 'durch' to express the same meaning.

For example you can say

```
Wir reisen um 7:00 Uhr (ab)
```

meaning *we leave at 7:00*

In this example *reisen* means starting a trip, you can't use *bereisen* here.

You can look [here](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/reisen#Bedeutunga) for more examples for each meaning of *reisen*.

Comment: I don't agree with that answer. Reisen and bereise are not interchangeable, as a rule.

Comment: @Ingmar can you give an example where it is not? I couldn't think of any and think it's a bit harsh to get downvoted without proper explanation. I might be wrong and accept being downvoted if I am, but I am here to learn as well.

Comment: They are different words. You can't use "bereisen" instead of reisen, as you yourself admitted, but it doesn't work the other way round, either, without rephrasing: "Australien bereisen" means to travel extensively in Australia. You can't simply use "reisen" here, although "herumreisen" might work.

Comment: @Pasoe I can't think of any example where exchanging **bereisen** and **reisen** would not change meaning. Could name an example where that works?

Comment: Sounds like we just have a different understanding. If I use "durch Australien reisen" instead of "Australien bereisen" I would say that I exchanged the words. I should have mentioned that I need more than just "reisen" to express the same meaning as "bereisen". If that is your only point I wouldn't say my answer is wrong though.

Comment: @Hulk as mentioned above:
"Australien bereisen" <--> "durch Australien reisen"
Is there a difference in the meaning?

Comment: Indeed there is. Australia is a bad example, perhaps, let's take a smaller, land-locked country like Austria. "Er bereiste Österreich" and "Er reiste durch Österreich (nach Italien)" are two different things.

Comment: @Pasoe "durch Australien reisen" sounds strange to me, unless you are just passing through (which would be kind of difficult in Australia)

Comment: @Ingmar Why would you add "nach Italien" if you dont want to express that? If you leave it out it **can** mean you are traveling to different places within Austria, it **could** also imply that you are on your way through Austria.

Comment: @Hulk it doesn't sound strange to me. However 'bereisen' sounds kind of old to me and I dont see it used very often, as mentioned in Ingmar's answer

Comment: Just to remove any ambiguity and to make my example more clear. If you don't agree, that's fine, but as far as I'm concerned reisen and bereisen are two different words. EOD.

Comment: @Ingmar I don't agree with my answer being wrong or such. As I see it, we only have different opinions. As a native speaker I don't understand why you can't exchange 'bereisen' with 'reisen' (+ 'durch' or something else fitting), as all examples I can think of sound valid and correct. 2nd EOD